# Equivalence classes in GAP

Tags: gap

I have a list and a function on the elements on this list. 
I want to define an equivalence relation on this list by saying that two elements are equivalent if the function applied to those elements gives the same results. Is there a way to obtain in GAP the euivalence classes (so the result should be a list of lists corresponding to the equivalence classes).
Example:
The list is

[ [ 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ] ]

and the function $f$ is taking the Maximum of the number of such an element.
Thus for example $f([ 3, 2, 2, 1 ])=3$.
The equivalence classes are in this example :

-[ 2, 2, 2, 1 ]

-[ 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 1 ]

-[ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can hold all objects in memory, it probably is easiest to once apply the function to get a list of values, then get equivalence classes of indices by (set of) values, and then get the lists. This can be done conveniently with the `List` and `Filtered` operations. In your example

```
gap> l:=[ [ 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 4,...
[ [ 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ] ]
gap> v:=List(l,Maximum);
[ 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 ]
gap> idx:=List(Set(v),x->Filtered([1..Length(v)],y->v[y]=x));
[ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5 ] ]
gap> List(idx,x->l{x});
[ [ [ 2, 2, 2, 1 ] ], [ [ 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ] ] ]
```

Note that if the values of the function are algebraic structures, and not just numbers, it can be worth to replace `Set` by `Unique` in line -5.

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty cool. the second step v:=List(l,Maximum); does not work if the Function depends on two arguments, like for example CoxeterPolynomial(NakayamaAlgebra(-,GF(3)) instead of Maximum, where - is the thing where I want the list to be put in. Is there a trick to fix this? (expect to apply NakayamaAlgebra(-,GF(3)) before, which I can do and it is also an option)

Comment: If the function takes further arguments you can use the inline function notation to wrap it into a one-argument function,e.g. replace `Maximum` by `x->BlaBla(FooBar(x,GF(3),99))`